# java decompress zipfile with unicode filenames

Tags: java, utf-8, zip, filenames, zipinputstream

How to decompress a zip file with unicode filename?
This is my code:

```
try {
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
    while (ze != null) {
        String fileName = new String(ze.getName().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(fileName);
        File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName );

        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int ch;
        StringBuffer buffer1 = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = zis.read()) > -1) {
            buffer1.append((char) ch);
        }
        osw.write(buffer1.toString());
        osw.close();
        outStream.close();

        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }

    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I receive the error: `UTFDataFormatException`:

```
06-05 08:46:33.394: W/System.err(777): java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad second or third byte at 6 
06-05 08:46:33.394: W/System.err(777): at java.nio.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode(ModifiedUtf8.java:56) 
06-05 08:46:33.426: W/System.err(777): at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:270) 
06-05 08:46:33.426: W/System.err(777): at com.learnlang.utility.ZipManager.unZipIt(ZipManager.java:62) 
06-05 08:46:33.434: W/System.err(777): at com.learnlang.HomeActivity$progressThread.run(HomeActivity.java:317)
```

My class is `ZipManager`.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Provide please full stacktrace of exception

Comment: 06-05 08:46:33.394: W/System.err(777): java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad second or third byte at 6
06-05 08:46:33.394: W/System.err(777):  at java.nio.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode(ModifiedUtf8.java:56)
06-05 08:46:33.426: W/System.err(777):  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:270)
06-05 08:46:33.426: W/System.err(777):  at com.learnlang.utility.ZipManager.unZipIt(ZipManager.java:62)
06-05 08:46:33.434: W/System.err(777):  at com.learnlang.HomeActivity$progressThread.run(HomeActivity.java:317)

My class is ZipManager

Comment: Are you sure that the filenames are UTF-8 encoded? It looks like decoding the UTF-8 filename failes.

Comment: How file names are encoded depends on the operating system. Are you on Windows, OS X, Linux, or something else?

Comment: Hi Shuttle1978, I just encounter the same problem here. Did you solve it at last?

Comment: I have the same problem! please provide your solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, it seems that your file is actually not in `UTF-8` encoding.

Furthermore, the problem is not with file's name. This line:

```
 String fileName = new String(ze.getName().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

is meaningless, because `ze.getName()` is already correct java string.

Comment: the filename that I'm tring to unzip is "de_Maße-und-Gewichte_de", I've tryed with only ze.getName() but it doesn't work

Comment: @shuttle1978 What do you mean by `it doesn't work'? What kind of exception do you receive in this case?

Comment: the same exception UTFDataFormatException

Comment: using 

File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator
      + e.getName());

the exception is the same

Comment: @shuttle1978 you receive the same exception only because problem is not with file's name, but with encoding of your entire file.

Comment: ok but if I decompress the file manually it works fine and I see the file "de_Maße-und-Gewichte_de" instead with the java code I've the problem